# Automated deployment of DSS datasource configuration

Tags: wso2, datasource, wso2-data-services-server

We have a "mavenized" project with several containers (wso2esb, wso2dss, tomcat) and many components to deploy to them.

We are trying to find a way to deploy the datasource configuration for all our DSS services but I notice it is stored in its own DB (H2).

Do you know if there is any way to declare something like a XML file in order to create the datasource in the DSS in an automated way?

I tried to see the documentation but did not find anything useful for automatic deployment (meaning without using the admin pages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you can use the Carbon data source configuration file `datasources.properties`, to provide this information. This file should be located at `$SERVER_ROOT/repository/conf`.

A sample for this configuration file can be found in [BPS sources](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/products/bps/modules/distribution/conf/datasources.properties).

After the data sources are defined using this, you can use them using the data source type "carbon data source" from data services.

Comment: Thanks, it is exaclty the information I needed. It works perfectly. I suggest anyway you put the same sample in the DSS project as well, because I was not aware (and not using) the BPS product.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily deploy artifacts with the hot deployment functionality in WSO2 Servers by simply copying them to a specific directory in the server.
 For Data Services Server you can copy the dbs files (in your case with the help of Maven) to `$WSO2DSS_HOME/repository/deployment/server/dataservices` dirctory. Similarly for BPELs its `$WSO2BPS_HOME/repository/deployment/server/bpel`

For CAR files created with carbon studio, its `$WSO2CARBON_HOME/repository/deployment/server/carbonapps`.
For ESB configs, its `$WSO2ESB_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs`.

Comment: We have already that mecanism implemented. The only issue is what kind of file/artifact we need to deploy the data-sources (E.g connection to Oracle). Is it a special file in the CAR? I cannot find documentation except "use the administration console" to create a datasource.