# How I can create manually datasource in BPS 2.1.2 (carbon 3.2.0)

Tags: wso2

How I can create manually datasource in BPS 2.1.2 (carbon 3.2.0)

Data source UI features added get null error.

Can I add it in to registry.xml file?

Thanks

Comment: This seems to be a known issue for 3.2.2 release and please follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428220/error-looking-up-a-data-source-null-in-appserver-4-1-2-of-wso2
Apply the same, in your case for BPS. 

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add data sources in registry.xml it is used to configure registry.Please refer this [documentation](http://wso2.org/project/bps/2.1.2/docs/bpel-installation-guide/bpel_installation_guide.html#Configure-WSO2-BPS-with-external-data-sources)

You can find a sample configuration [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/products/bps/modules/distribution/conf/datasources.properties).

refere these threads if you need more information.

[Automated deployment of DSS datasource configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777975/automated-deployment-of-dss-datasource-configuration)

[WSO2 ESB - Data Services Server Feature - How to use Data Sources to swap data source on fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11196914/wso2-esb-data-services-server-feature-how-to-use-data-sources-to-swap-data-s)

Comment: Hi Shelan, thank for the answer very soon. Sorry for the registry miss. I mast add my "Available Data Sources
" into BPS 2.1.2 for deploy .dbs file. Where my new datasource definition is stored( /conf or DB )? Thank Again.

Comment: you can add a carbon data sources definitions in repository/conf.

Comment: Which config file I must modify. Can you get me an example file conf?

Comment: please refer the answer i have improved it.

Comment: I have add my datasource into datasource.properties file.(synapse.datasources=bpsds,oracle) This work fine. The new datasource is visible on UI BPS. I can't edit it. Can I deploy .dbs file whitout UI BPS(I get error NoSuchFieldError: fileItemsMap..). This is know bug BPS 2.1.2 Carbon 3.2.0. I going to CARBON 4.0.0 in the future to solve all.

Comment: I solved it for now. I manually create "datasources" directory  into repository/deployment/server and copied it  .dbs files. I going to carbon 4.0.0 very soon. Thank very much all